# Não consigo gravar texto formatado com tinyCME no banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, html5, mysqli, tinymce

O código sem o editor de texto grava no banco de dados.
Depois que coloquei o editor, o botão submit do formulário não envia dados.
Também estou interessada em gravar trechos de códigos de programação.
Abaixo está o código do formulário.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
    session_start(); 
} 

if(empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php'); exit;
} 

include_once 'modules/crud_resposta.php';
?>

<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <?php include('templates/head_content.html.php'); ?>
  <title>Início</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
?>
<?php include('templates/navbar.html.php'); ?>
    <?php include('templates/header.html.php'); ?>
        <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            tinymce.init({selector:'textarea',
            plugins: 'code'});
        </script>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3 class="text-center">Responder Discussão</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <form method="post">
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-         form-group controls">
                            <label>Conteúdo:</label>
                            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control ckeditor" placeholder="resposta" name="conteudo" required data-validation-required-message="Favor, insira a resposta."></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" name="inserir" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Responder</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Cancelar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php
        include('templates/footer.html.php');
    ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

E abaixo está o trecho do código do CRUD.

```
if(isset($_POST['inserir'])){
    $conteudo_resposta = trim($_POST['conteudo']);
    $conteudo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $conteudo_resposta);
    $data_criacao = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $id_usuario = $_GET['usuario'];
    $id_discussao = $_GET['discussao'];

    $inserir_resposta = mysqli_prepare($conexao, "INSERT INTO resposta(conteudo, data_criacao, id_discussao, id_usuario) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");

    if($inserir_resposta){

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($inserir_resposta, "ssii", $conteudo, $data_criacao, $id_discussao, $id_usuario);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($inserir_resposta);
        mysqli_stmt_close($inserir_resposta);

        ?>
  <script>return alert('Resposta inserida com sucesso!');</script>
  <?php
            header('Location:respostas.php?discussao=' .$id_discussao);
    }
    else{
                ?>
      <script>alert('Erro ao efetuar a resposta!');</script>
      <?php
                die(mysqli_error($conexao));
    }

    if(!$inserir_resposta){
        die(mysqli_error($conexao));
    }   
}
```

Comment: Luana, não é retornada nenhuma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Não, não retorna.

Comment: Tente adicionar logo após a primeira tag de abertura: <?php o código: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
Com isso será possível ver as saídas de erro.

Comment: Apareceu esse erro no console do inspecionador de elemento:

"An invalid form control with name='conteudo' is not focusable."

Comment: Acho que no lugar de button você teria que usar input. Exemplo: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:How-to_implement_TinyMCE_in_PHP e http://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/117385-tinymce/

Comment: Usei o input e ainda assim não funcionava.

Comment: Precisei retirar o required para que funcione. Assim, vou ter que validar o formulário com javascript mesmo...

Comment: Só por curiosidade, já chegou a verificar se o erro ocorre nos navegadores chrome, firefox... Ou somente em um deles?

Comment: O erro aconteceu no Firefox também.